# How to check if a word appears in ID(location in element list) of another word(key)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list:

```
lst = [" ","1- make your choice", "2- put something and make", "3- make something happens",
"4- giulio took his choice so make","5- make your choice", "6- put something and make",
"7- make something happens", "8- giulio took his choice so make","9- make your choice",
"10- put something and make", "11- make something happens", "12- giulio took his choice so make"]
```

I created two dictionaries, first where i have as key the ID(number) of position of words in lst, and in value i have the words in that position.

```
{1: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 2: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 3: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 4: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make'], 5: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 6: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 7: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 8: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make'], 9: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 10: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 11: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 12: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make']}
```

---

In the second dictionarie, as key i have all words in lst, and as value i have two set()

```
{'and': (set([]), set([2, 10, 6])), 'happens': (set([]), set([11, 3, 7])), 'his': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'giulio': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'make': (set([]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])), 'took': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'choice': (set([]), set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12])), 'so': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'something': (set([]), set([2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11])), 'put': (set([]), set([2, 10, 6])), 'your': (set([]), set([1, 5, 9]))}
```

In second set i put all ID where the key is located for example:

```
'choice': (set([]), set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12]))
```

---

In first set i want to put all words which are simultaneously in all ID of key choice, example:

If we look in the lst we can see that the only word that appears in all the ID of the key choice is 'make', so the result of key choice is:

```
'choice': (set(['make']), set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12]))
```

except the word 'choice', of course

any suggestion on how to see if a word appears in all the same ID of the key of second dictionary? and put it in the first set?

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier if in the first one instead of lists you have sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the id's, flatten the all the lists to one big list and check if each word `count` is equal to the number of lists.

It's only one option which can be done with less expensive flow but i didn't want to complicate things.

**Solution**:

```
my_dict = {1: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 2: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 3: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 4: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make'], 5: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 6: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 7: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 8: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make'], 9: ['make', 'your', 'choice'], 10: ['put', 'something', 'and', 'make'], 11: ['make', 'something', 'happens'], 12: ['giulio', 'took', 'his', 'choice', 'so', 'make']}
words = {'and': (set([]), set([2, 10, 6])), 'happens': (set([]), set([11, 3, 7])), 'his': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'giulio': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'make': (set([]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])), 'took': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'choice': (set([]), set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12])), 'so': (set([]), set([8, 12, 4])), 'something': (set([]), set([2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11])), 'put': (set([]), set([2, 10, 6])), 'your': (set([]), set([1, 5, 9]))}

for k, v in words.items():
    flatten_list = [elem for id_ in v[1] for elem in my_dict[id_]]
    words[k][0].update(set([word for word in flatten_list if word != k if flatten_list.count(word) == len(v[1])]))

print words
```

**Output**:

```
{'and': (set(['put', 'make', 'something']), set([2, 10, 6])), 'his': (set(['make', 'so', 'giulio', 'took', 'choice']), set([8, 4, 12])), 'took': (set(['make', 'his', 'so', 'giulio', 'choice']), set([8, 4, 12])), 'choice': (set(['make']), set([1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12])), 'something': (set(['make']), set([2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11])), 'put': (set(['and', 'make', 'something']), set([2, 10, 6])), 'your': (set(['make', 'choice']), set([1, 5, 9])), 'happens': (set(['make', 'something']), set([3, 11, 7])), 'giulio': (set(['make', 'his', 'so', 'took', 'choice']), set([8, 4, 12])), 'make': (set([]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])), 'so': (set(['make', 'his', 'giulio', 'took', 'choice']), set([8, 4, 12]))}
```